# BLOB URL not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, url, safari, blob

I'am using D3 to generate a graph and want to export this to an image, which works fine in all browsers except Safari. The code generates a D3 SVG, which is used in a BLOB, which is used as an image, which is added to a canvas which can be exported.

```js
var blob = new Blob([source], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Put the svg into an image tag so that the Canvas element can read it in.
var img = d3.select('body').append('img')
 .attr('width', width)
 .attr('height', height)
 .node();

img.onload = function(){
  // Some method which is never called
}
img.src = url;
```

In Safari, the onload function is never triggered and the image element is also not displaying the image. I logged both the blob element and URL and both seem fine (if i manually open the blob URL in safari it downloads the SVG code). But it won't display it as an image and therefore i can't export it.

Something i noticed is that when i inspect the img element and open the src in a new tab it opens on the URL  https://www.mysite.nl/mypage/blob:https://www.mysite.nl/2a173f60-8b34-4b1c-894b-4ff6adcfe9fa

So for some reason Safari interprets the BLOB URL as a relative instead of an absolute one. Anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Safari doesn't like your Blob's MIME Type.

The correct one is `image/svg+xml` the charset header is useless, and while I'm not sure it's actually allowed to be there, it is anyway useless.

So remove the `;charset=utf-8` part from your `type` option, and you'll be fine:

```js
var blob = new Blob(['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><rect y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" ry="15" x="0"></rect></svg>'], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml' // this is the only MIME for SVG
});
document.body.appendChild(
  new Image()
).src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: I just noticed i forgot to mark this reply, and thank you for it, removing the charset solved my problem.
However, i don't think it's a duplicate question, even though the solution is the same, since my question is specifically about the desktop browser, whereas his is specifically about the mobile version.

Comment: @A.Bos these questions are duplicates. I'm not sure, but it may be a webkit issue, which means you could experience it not only on the ios or desktop Safari versions, but even on other browsers based on the same webkit code base. But I closed the other one as a dupe of this one.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido removing the ;charset=utf-8 from the type worked for us too!  There must be some bad code on the Internet recommending that.  Goodness!

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me a lot of work. Cheers! @Kaiido